# "JsonResult" não contém um construtor que aceita 0 argumentos

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, .net-core

Estou tentando retornar um JsonResult para minha View, mas ele está retornando o seguinte errro.

> "JsonResult" não contém um construtor que aceita 0 argumentos

Saberiam me ajudar amigos ?

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllSchedule()
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException($"Não é possível carregar o usuário com o ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
    }

    var events = _scheduleManager.GetAllSchedule(user.Id);

    return new JsonResult { Data = events, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };

    }
```

Na linha do return estou recebendo o erro que citei acima, poderiam me ajudar ?

Comment: É .Net Core, certo? tente sem o `JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`, assim `return new JsonResult(new { Data = events })`. Estou pelo celular e jaja gero uma resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No .Net Core não tem a opção `JsonRequestBehavior` ele é gerenciado pelo atributo que fica em cima do `IActionResult`, no seu caso você já informa que é um *Get* com o `HttpGet`.

Há duas opções, primeiro retornar o `JsonResult` que é a classe e no seu construtuor espera um objeto ou um objeto mais uma instancia de `JsonSerializerSettings` ou usar o método `Json` que está dentro da classe `Controller` e irá retornar um `JsonResult` e este também espera um objeto ou um objeto mais uma instancia de `JsonSerializerSettings`

Sua `IActionResult` ficaria assim:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllSchedule()
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException($"Não é possível carregar o usuário com o ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
    }

    var events = _scheduleManager.GetAllSchedule(user.Id);

    return new JsonResult(new { Data = events });
}
```

Ou

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllSchedule()
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException($"Não é possível carregar o usuário com o ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
    }

    var events = _scheduleManager.GetAllSchedule(user.Id);

    return Json(new { Data = events });
}
```

Quanto a classe `JsonSerializerSettings` você pode ver mais na [documentação oficial](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm)